# CLR Profiling API

Tags: c#, c++, clr

Все привет.

Волей случая пришлось разрабатывать собственный профилировщик для `CLR` и наткнулся на несколько не понятных моментов:

1. Как я понимаю событие `ICorProfilerCallback2::HandleCreated` вызывается в том случае, если для некоторого объекта с `initialObjectId` создается дескриптор сборки мусора `handleId`, а событие `ICorProfilerCallback2::HandleDestroyed` - вызывается для дескриптора сборки мусора в том случае, если он был обработан, то есть связанный с ним объект был удален из памяти. Однако, в процессе профилирования я заметил, что не для всех дескрипторов созданных вызовом `HandleCreated` вызывается `HandleDestroyed`.

Что может быть причиной и как это следует интерпретировать?

2. При обработке событий `ICorProfilerCallback::MovedReferences` заметил следующее: предположим у нас есть два дапазон адресов A...B и C...D. В процессе обработки объекты из диапазона C...D переехали в E...F, а то что находилось в A...B было уничтожено. Однако, при следующей сборке мусора GC начинает активно перемещать блоки памяти в диапазоне A...B, хотя они уже были очищены ранее и созданий объектов в этом диапазоне адресов зафиксировано не было.

- Это какая то особенность работы `GC` или я что то не учитываю?
- Если что то не учитываю, то что?
- В какую сторону смотреть?

3. И как вишенка на тортике: объекты соответствующие диапазону адресов A...B, которые так мужественно пытается переместить `GC` нашлись в списке объектов, для которых был создан, но не выполнен дескриптор сборки мусора.

Все эти 3 пункта не дают спокойно жить уже третий день.

Кто сталкивался с подобным помогите плизз)